# How to "refresh/redraw" wpf ribbon control?

Tags: c#, wpf

My binding property points at one value, but display previous. The binding is ok - it is working fine and this is the only bug - frozen values. I only need to redraw  this ribbon controls. how to do this? 
 **This controls are not in observable collection - they just placed on form

I HAVE implemented RaisePropertyChanged... All this works fine BUT my app initialized from several ways. The question not about binding - it is about re-Drawing ribbon wpf controls

Comment: What property isn't updated?? Do you implement OnPropertyChange interface?

Comment: If it is just about redrawing the control you can do that by Invoking the Dispatcher. However I don't recommend it since your problem is more of the type why do you need to repaint it.
   public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement)
   {
      uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);
   }

Comment: how you defined EmptyDelegate in your code?